# What does the first stanza of the Aswhamedha sacrifice mean?

Tags: vedas, translation-request, sanskrit, ashwamedha, taittirya-brahmana

This is the first stanza of the Ashwamedha yajna in the Taittiriya Brahmana. What does it mean in English? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how [this journal paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3143199) translates it:

> He (the Sacrificer, i.e. the king) offers the samgrahani ishti. (When he is about to offer that oblation, he says:) “I will keep this community together (under my authority).”

The paper also provides this explanation on what the verse is saying:

> According to Apastamba 20.1.4, the Sacrificer offers the samgrahani ishti on the full moon of Chaitra (March-April).  This ishti by which he obtains the power to keep the members of his clan under his authority is offered not on the sacrificial ground that is to be chosen for the Ashwamedha (horse-sacrifice), but in the hut where the Sacrificer daily performs the oblations of the domestic ritual.